# Best Practice - Node Template Logic

Tags: 6, nodes

I have a node template file that requires a lot of logic. So much so that in order to make things easier I have created functions inside my custom node.tpl file. What is best practice for separating logic from the node.tpl?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [template_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_node/6) function. Add this to your template.php in your theme and do whatever you have to do.